# Event that change percentage to integer and vice-versa in highcharts(piecharts).

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[image]

As in image you can see the fee collected and fee due are in % i want to give user option like dropdown where they can select either in % or in number.when event changes it will show in % and in number.i have already made changes on hover event that we can see.
Here is my code

```
var totalAmount = parseFloat(parseData[0][0].total_amount);
var paidAmount = parseFloat(parseData[0][0].paid_amount);
var dueAmount = totalAmount - paidAmount;

$("#chart-container,#chart-container2").removeClass('hide')
var slicedData = {
    name: 'Fees Collected',
    y: paidAmount,
    sliced: true,
    selected: true
}
var array = [slicedData,['Fees Due',dueAmount]];
drawChart(array);


function drawChart(chartData){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: ($("#chart-container2").offset().top)-250},'slow');
    chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart-container',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fee Chart'
        },
        tooltip: {
           formatter:function(){
                return '<b>'+ (this.key) +' :  '+ this.y +' </b>';
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 2) +' %';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Fee Ratio',
            data: chartData
        }]
    });
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/swgvawmL/ use series.update() on dropdown change event. Depending on its value, change the format of the data labels.

Comment: Thank you so much it works for me.